# Elmah in a N-Tier Environment

Tags: asp.net, elmah, n-tier-architecture

I have a 3-tier web application using `MVC` - `WCF` - `MSSQL`.

I like Elmah however it currently does not follow our security rules. Our tiers communicate using trusted security so having the Web tier talk directly to the database tier is frowned upon. I'm not sure/aware of a standard for error logging so any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: @JLsaak - did you get this working in n-tiers if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love ELMAH, but I can understand not wanting the web tier talking directly to the data tier...I suggest that if you want to use ELMAH, you use the [XML logging implementation](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorLogImplementations). If you absolutely have to have it write to your database, you could download the source code, and extend the memory logging implementation to call a WCF service to log the exception.

As far as a standard for error logging, every developer is going to have their own opinion. [This is an old blog post by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GoodExceptionManagementRulesOfThumb.aspx), but a good one that talks about exception management.

Comment: With the XML implementation, is there a reason to be concerned with the logs taking up a large amount of disk space? That was my initial thought and reason why I looked into the database implementation.

Comment: Well it will depend on your definition of large of course, but also on the number of errors, how often you clear the log, etc.